# How to manage/save state for a widget with many checkboxes?

Tags: checkbox, flutter, state

I'm creating a Flutter app to store progress for board game characters, I want to allow a user to check up to 18 checkboxes, where the checkboxes are grouped in threes:

[image: example]

My first approach was to code this widget such that I have as little code reused as possible.

`CheckboxGroup` is a `Row` widget with a checkmark icon, ":", and three checkboxes as children.
`CheckboxGridRow` is a `Row` widget with two `CheckboxGroup`s as children.
`CheckboxGrid` is a `Column` widget with three `CheckboxGridRows` as children.

```
-> CheckboxGrid
  -> CheckboxGridRow
    -> CheckboxGroup
    -> CheckboxGroup
  -> CheckboxGridRow
    -> CheckboxGroup
    -> CheckboxGroup
  -> CheckboxGridRow
    -> CheckboxGroup
    -> CheckboxGroup
```

This works fine for UI purposes, but I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to manage/store state for it. I expect that I will use a `List<bool>` to store true/false for state, but where should the state change and database logic be for this setup?

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, the state only goes down the tree. So there aren't many solutions:

The state must be stored by a common ancestor of all of your checkboxes.

From there, it's fairly easy to deduce what "checkbox" and "checkbox group" should do: UI

---

#### The checkbox widget

Nothing special. Any checkbox will do, as long as it has:

- a "checked" boolean
- an "onChanged" callback.

The default [Checkbox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html) or [Switch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Switch-class.html) should do just fine.

#### The checkbox group

This widget will map a list of options into a list of checkboxes and determine if they are checked or not.

It'll have usually three parameters:

- The list of all options
- The list of selected options
- an "onChanged" callback

Here's a typical implementation:

```dart
@immutable
class Option<T> {
  Option({@required this.value, @required this.label});

  final T value;
  final Widget label;
}

class CheckboxGroup<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  CheckboxGroup({
    Key key,
    @required this.options,
    @required this.selectedValues,
    @required this.onChange,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Option<T>> options;
  final List<T> selectedValues;
  final ValueChanged<List<T>> onChange;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        for (final option in options) ...[
          Checkbox(
            key: ObjectKey(option.value),
            value: selectedValues.contains(option.value),
            onChanged: (res) {
              if (res) {
                onChange([...selectedValues, option.value]);
              } else {
                onChange([...selectedValues]..remove(option.value));
              }
            },
          ),
          option.label,
        ]
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

#### The state

Compared to the previous snippet, it's dead simple:

It simply declared a bunch of fields, sends them to `CheckboxGroup`, and call `setState` when needed.

```dart
enum Foo { a, b, c }
enum Bar { a, b, c }

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  List<Foo> foo = const [];
  List<Bar> bar = const [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        CheckboxGroup<Foo>(
          selectedValues: foo,
          options: [
            for (final value in Foo.values)
              Option(value: value, label: Text(value.toString()))
          ],
          onChange: (value) => setState(() => foo = value),
        ),
        CheckboxGroup<Bar>(
          selectedValues: bar,
          options: [
            for (final value in Bar.values)
              Option(value: value, label: Text(value.toString()))
          ],
          onChange: (value) => setState(() => bar = value),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```